# Create static front-page with 3-5 recent posts

Tags: loop, frontpage, template-hierarchy, recent-posts

I am struggling with front/landing page customization for my custom designed theme. I have designed custom theme and pretty much coded it using the *Underscore boilerplate*.

As I understands, the codex suggests that I create a front-page.php and customize it there. In *setting>reading* I selected A static/Front page (my desired page where I change the static welcoming message). Underneath I want to have 3-5 recent posts with thumbnails (enabled in my functions) and excerpts.

My front-page.php:

```
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <h2>Recent Posts</h2>
        <ul>
        <?php
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
            $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
            foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
            }
        ?>
        </ul>

</main><!-- #main -->
```

This works, however I have no clue how to load thumbnails + excerpts. Most importantly is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tend not to go with [`wp_get_recent_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) or even [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) for custom queries like this. By default, template tags like `the_excerpt()` is not available to these functions, and you have to make use of [`setup_postdata($post)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) to have access to these template tags.

I would personally use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in a case like this which is more flexible, specially when have a custom query that needs to be paginated.

Here is an example of a custom query to get the newest 5 posts. Note: I have not included any html mark-up. For a list of all available arguments, check out the link I've provided in `WP_Query`

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$rp = new WP_Query( $args );

if($rp->have_posts()) :
    while($rp->have_posts()) : $rp->the_post();

       the_title(); // posttitle
       if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
          the_post_thumbnail(); //display the thumbnail
       } 

       the_excerpt(); // displays the excerpt

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); // always always remember to reset postdata when using a custom query, very important
endif;
```

For further reading:

- [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)
- [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) (Just a note here, certain examples uses [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), which should never be used. Rather use `WP_Query` to construct custom queries)
- [Creating a static front page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`get_the_post_thumbnail($recent['ID'], 'post-thumbnail');`

in order to get the thumbnail. Unfortunately, there is no way to get the excerpt, you can however trim the content using PHP.

Alternatively, there's a hook I haven't used before, you can try it and see i its works for the excerpt:

`get_post_field();`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image using this code: 
`$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium', false, '' ); $thumbnailSrc = $src[0];`

where  **'medium'**  is the thumbnail size, this can be changed to *thumbnail, large or any special size*  created with thumbnail support on functions.php ej. 
`add_image_size( 'postslider', 680,310, true );`

I'm printing the image with  `img src="php echo $src; ?` don't forget  to include the php tags inside the code

For the excerpt the simple way is  **the_excerpt();**   instead of  **the_content();**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the two previous answers will get you close, but as I understand it, you might need to change the `foreach` loop into a second wordpress loop call, after the custom query (see an example [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) in the "examples" section):

The reason I suggest using the wordpress loop is that the function `the_excerpt()` only works inside the standard loop framework.  If you're inside "the Loop," you'd use

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'your-custom-post-size-here' );
```

rather than

```
get_the_post_thumbnail
```

as Yusri Mathews suggests.  His answer will work outside of "the Loop," in cases like your `foreach` loop.

But as mentioned above, if you're in "the Loop," you have access to `the_excerpt()` which should get you where you're going.